# Variable Number of Operations to Perform on Data

Tags: algorithm, templates, c++11

Please correct me if this is not possible with C++ but here is the idea: I have a set of data that I would like to, at runtime, perform addition (+), subtraction(-), and/or multiplication(*). Currently I have three for loops to achieve this, which means it can be slow. I'd like to put all these operations into a single loop.

pseudocode:

```
Data ApplyOperations(const Data &a, ... const Data &n, OperatorA(), ..., OperatorN()) {
for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
   result[i] = a[i] OperatorA() ... n[i] OperatorN();  
return result;
}
```

This way, I can apply N operations in whatever order I want in a single loop. Can someone point me into the right direction to achieve this in C++11?

Thanks!

Comment: Reducing your 3 `for` loops into one isn't going to speed up your code if you're doing 3 times as much work in each iteration.

Comment: So you're saying `for(0->N) x+=a; for(0->N) x*=b; for(0->N) x-=c` is equivalent to `for(0->N) x = (x+a)*b-c`?

Comment: It's the same number of operations, yes.  However, those two code snippets will produce wildly different results.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two nested loops, one on an "array" of N sets and operators, and one on M elements in each set.

From a complexity analysis point of view it makes no difference which loop is the outer one; the complexity is O(N*M). However, if the data sets passed as argument to your functions are in fact the same set, then on most modern architectures you will get a much better performance by having the iteration on the data items as the outer one. The reason is the effect of caches. If you iterate on the data over and over, you're going to have more cache misses, which have a very heavy effect on performance. Of course, if you're rally passing different data set for each operator, then there is no difference.